# Converting promises to async/await - Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a dataService function in React that does my API fetching. I tried converting to async/await block but seem to hit a roadblock.

Using promises:

```
const dataService = (url, options, dataToPost) => {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const { requestAction, successAction, failureAction } = options.actions;

        if (options.shouldRequest(getState())) {
            dispatch(requestAction());
            const promise = axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
            return promise
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        return dispatch(successAction(response, dispatch));
                    }
                    return Promise.reject(response);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    if (error.response.status === 302) {
                        window.location = '/view';
                    }
                    dispatch(openErrorDialog());
                    return dispatch(failureAction(error));
                });
        }
        return Promise.reject(new Error('FETCHING'));
    };
};
```

Using async/await:

```js
 const dataService = async (url, options, dataToPost) => {

     return async (dispatch, getState) => {
         let url;
         const {requestAction, successAction, failureAction} = options.actions;

         if (options.shouldRequest(getState())) {
             dispatch(requestAction());
             const promise = axios.get(url, {withCredentials: true});
             try {
                 const response = await promise;
                 if (response.status === 200) {
                     return dispatch(successAction(response, dispatch));
                 }
                 return Promise.reject(response);
             } catch (error) {
                 return dispatch(failureAction(error));
             }
         }
         return Promise.reject(new Error('FETCHING'));
     };
 };
```

The error is "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.". The promises code works perfecty. I am already using thunk. Please advice.

Comment: what you've done makes no sense, in that `const promise = dataToPost ? ....`  wont be a promise - lets face it, all you've done is mark `dataService` as async, so now it doesn't return the function declared within, it returns a promise of that function

Comment: Try removing async keyword from dataService to `dataService = (url, options, dataToPost)`
This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059724/how-do-i-resolve-actions-must-be-plain-objects-use-custom-middleware-for-async

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you truly want to change Promise -> async/await then the changes are as follows:

For a start, you DONT want dataService to be `async` as that will mean it returns a Promise, which changes how it needs to be called - you dont' wnat that

Secondly, changing

```
  const promise = axios.get ...
  promise.then(response ....
```

to

```
  const promise = await axios.get ...
  promise.then(response ....
```

wont work ...

it needs to be

```
const response = await axios.get ...
```

no need for the promise variable

Even so, you're **still using promises** in your converted code ... which now is only different by having `async` keywords for no reason

Here's how your (original) code should be converted to async/await

note the total LACK of the word Promise in what follows:

```
const dataService = (url, options, dataToPost) => {

    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const { requestAction, successAction, failureAction } = options.actions;

        if (options.shouldRequest(getState())) {
            const data = typeof dataToPost === 'string' ? { data: dataToPost } : dataToPost;
            dispatch(requestAction());
            try {
                const response = dataToPost
                    ? await axios.post(url, data, { withCredentials: true })
                    : await axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return dispatch(successAction(response, dispatch));
                }
                throw response;
            } catch(error) {
                if (error.response.status === 302) {
                    window.location = '/view';
                }
                dispatch(openErrorDialog());
                return dispatch(failureAction(error));
            }
        }
        throw new Error('FETCHING');
    };
};
```

Answer (score 5):

`await axios.post(url, data, { withCredentials: true })` does not return promise, it returns the real response of the request.

do not use then-catch when using async-await, use try-catch instead.
here is the fix

```
try {
    const response = dataToPost
        ? await axios.post(url, data, { withCredentials: true })
        : await axios.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
    if (response.status === 200) {
        return dispatch(successAction(response, dispatch));
    }
    return Promise.reject(response);
} catch (err) {
    if (error.response.status === 302) {
        window.location = '/view';
    }
    dispatch(openErrorDialog());
    return dispatch(failureAction(error));
}
```

Comment: @Ben: ??? Every `async` function returns a `Promise` object. The `await` statement operates on a `Promise`, waiting until the `Promise` resolves` or rejects. So @Gianfranco Fertino is correct.