# How to modify this React code into Async/Await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code:

```
function getList() {
    return functionList()
        .then((list) => functionDetails())
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

how to convert it to async/await?

Comment: https://umaar.com/dev-tips/182-typescript-async-await/

Comment: https://javascript.info/async-await best examples

Comment: Are you sure you are you don't want to use the result of `functionList()`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done into the issue and any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: This will work as is with `async / await`,  although I would remove the `catch` if this is not a top level call, otherwise the callee is not going to know there was an error as your swallowing it up.  And what has the above code got to do with React?

Comment: There are [many, many questions about converting promise/then based code to async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+promise+to+async+await). Please demonstrate what make this one different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting promises to async/await - Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272701/converting-promises-to-async-await-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the call to the awaited function in a try-catch to handle the error, and then run your `.then` code in the `finally` block

```
async function getList() {
    try {
        const result = await functionList();
        return ((result) => functionDetails()());
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, this has a different semantics. It calls `functionDetails` in any case, whereas OP calls it only when `functionList` didn't reject ...

Comment: Will the return inside the catch not prevent the finally block from running if there's an error?

Comment: No, the `finally` is executed no matter what you do in the `try` or the `catch` block. That's the whole purpose of `finally`

Comment: So if we raise the call to functionDetails inside the try block that seems to work correctly