# Why does my application return 'Actions must be plain objects, use custom middleware for async action'

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to set the user's current location in state using redux, but whenever I try I keep getting the error `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions`. Everywhere I look it states this is an error of not having thunk, but as you can see from my store.js below I have `applyMiddleware(thunk)` in my store.
Here are all of my files associated with this action:

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const composeEnhancers = window._REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE_ || compose;

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer, 
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : f => f
      )
);

export default store;
```

locationAction.js

```
export const setLocationState = () => {
    dispatch => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_LOCATION,
                payload: position
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Note: Even when I got rid of the dispatch and just had the `setLocationState()` function `return type: SET_LOCATION` I would get the same error, so that's leading me to believe that I may have configured something incorrectly somewhere.

locationReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_LOCATION:
            return {
                ...state,
                position: action.payload
            }

        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

index.jsx

```
import { setLocationState } from '../../../actions/locationActions'

const locationState = useSelector(state => state.location);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(setLocationState()) // <- Here is where error occurs
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059724/how-do-i-resolve-actions-must-be-plain-objects-use-custom-middleware-for-async)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setLocationState` looks buggy:

```js
export const setLocationState = () => {
    dispatch => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_LOCATION,
                payload: position
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Here, `dispatch => {}` is *creating* a new arrow function, but not *returning* that arrow function.  So, `setLocationState` is actually going to end up returning `undefined`, which is not a valid action object.

The simple fix here should just be adding a `return` in front: `return dispatch => {`.

Comment: This in combination with changing `dispatch(setLocationState())` to `dispatch(setLocationState)` solved my issue

Comment: `dispatch(setLocationState)` looks wrong, because `setLocationState` as seen in this example is a _thunk action creator_, which returns a _thunk function_ that is what is actually passed to dispatch. I'd encourage you to read through https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic and https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-7-standard-patterns for explanations of how to do this correctly.