# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to push these two variables `current` and `duration` to the redux store. And I'm getting this error. I'm new to this so can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
  const timeUpdateHandler = (e) => {
    const current = e.target.currentTime;
    const duration = e.target.duration;

    dispatch(timerUpdate(current, duration));
  };
```

This is the action creator in the store file:

```
export const timerUpdate = (current, duration) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log(current);

  dispatch({
    type: PLAYER_TIMER_UPDATE,
    payload: {
      currentTime: current,
      duration: duration,
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059724/how-do-i-resolve-actions-must-be-plain-objects-use-custom-middleware-for-async)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, your action creator does not return an `object` but a `Promise<object>`.
This is because of the `async` keyword before your action creator.

The [async keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) wraps the result in a promise. The code chunk you have posted does not have any async functionality so you can safely remove it.

On the other hand, if you do want async actions, try using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) library as suggested by HMR

Comment: Hey, I added thunk and now it is working like how it should. That async was put there by mistake. Thanks.