# How to fetch api in Redux/Redux-thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm new to redux. I can't call an API. Every other action like increment,decrement etc. are working fine but get_posts() is not working.
Please help me, and additional info on best practice would be too helpful. Thanks
I have already applied redux-thunk middleware but can't call an API. I'm stuck on redux for days.

Reducer

```
const countReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + action.payload;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return state - 1;
    case "get_posts":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default countReducer;
```

Action

```
import axios from "axios";

export const increment = (nr) => {
  return {
    type: "INCREMENT",
    payload: nr,
  };
};

export const decrement = () => {
  return {
    type: "DECREMENT",
  };
};

export const get_posts = () => {
  return {
    type: "get_posts",
    payload: fetchPosts,
  };
};

export function fetchPosts() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    dispatch(get_posts());
  };
}
```

Dispatcher/App.js

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { increment, decrement, get_posts } from "./action";
function App() {
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
  const isLogged = useSelector((state) => state.isLogged);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter {counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(increment(5))}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())}>Decrement</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(get_posts())}>Get API</button>
      {isLogged ? <h3>Valuable info I shouldnt</h3> : "NOt logged"}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Try to put async on `getPosts()` function and also add an `await` statement on that line where you're calling `fetchPosts()`.

Comment: What error are you facing?

Comment: It's returning null, Not any values

Comment: Are you still getting `null` when you await the function call as I mentioned above?

Comment: @Blessing Now getting this error.  "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
"

Comment: you can refer to the answer I provided below and see what happens.

Comment: @OsamaAshraf there's a good explanation for what is happening in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059724/how-do-i-resolve-actions-must-be-plain-objects-use-custom-middleware-for-async/54066862

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JoshuaAsare. It really worked. May you achieve all the good things. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake that's happening is that you're calling `fetchPosts` instead of `fetchPosts()` because it's a function. To make sure that you're getting your data you have to await the calling of `fetchPosts` like this.

```
export const get_posts = async () => {
  return {
    type: "get_posts",
    payload: await fetchPosts(),
  };
};
```

Comment: Figured it:-  export const get_posts = () => {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    console.log(res.data[0].id);
    dispatch({
      type: "get_posts",
      payload: [res.data[0].id],
    });
  };
};

Answer (score 0):

you wrong flow dude, i will try give the correct line code in your wrong line code

Dispatcher/App.js

```
import { increment, decrement, fetchPosts} from "./action";
...
...
<button onClick={() => dispatch(fetchPosts())}>Get API</button>
...
```

note: dispatch the action (function) which using for fetch the api

Action

```
...
export const get_posts = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: "get_posts",
    payload,
  };
};

export function fetchPosts() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
      try {
        const {data} = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
        dispatch(get_posts(data));
      catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
  };
}
```

note: dispatch the action type function and bring the response as a paramater payload