# Trying to use redux-thunk, but it displays error even though everything seems fine to me

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, dispatch, react-thunk

So I am following a tutorial where redux-thunk is implemented, and have done everything as it is in the video, but I still get this error:

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise'. You may need to add middleware to your store setup to handle dispatching other values, such as 'redux-thunk' to handle dispatching functions.

Here is how the code looks like:

```
index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
    
import reducers from './reducers';
    
import App from './App';
    
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
    
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is the action

```
actions/posts.js

export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.createPost(post);

        dispatch({ type: 'CREATE', payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The reducer:

```
const reducer = (posts = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_ALL':
            return action.payload;
        case 'CREATE':
            return [ ...posts, action.payload];
        default:
            return posts;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

And the file where the error occurs:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextField, Button, Typography, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import FileBase from 'react-file-base64';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import useStyles from './styles';
import { createPost } from '../../api';

export default function Form() {
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
        creator: '', 
        title: '', 
        message: '', 
        tags: '', 
        selectedFile: ''
    });
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        dispatch(createPost(postData));
    }

    const clear = () => {

    }

    return (
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className={`${classes.root} ${classes.form}`} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Typography variant="h6">Creating a Memory</Typography>
            <TextField 
                name="creator"
                variant="outlined"
                label="Creator"
                fullWidth
                value={postData.creator}
                onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, creator: e.target.value })}
            />
            <TextField 
                name="title"
                variant="outlined"
                label="Title"
                fullWidth
                value={postData.title}
                onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, title: e.target.value })}
            />
            <TextField 
                name="message"
                variant="outlined"
                label="Message"
                fullWidth
                value={postData.message}
                onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, message: e.target.value })}
            />
            <TextField 
                name="tags"
                variant="outlined"
                label="Tags"
                fullWidth
                value={postData.tags}
                onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, tags: e.target.value })}
            />
            <div className={classes.fileInput}>
                <FileBase 
                    type="file"
                    multiple={false}
                    onDone={({base64}) => setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64 })}
                />
            </div>
            <Button className={classes.buttonSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" type="submit" fullWidth>Submit</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="small" onClick={clear} fullWidth>Clear</Button>
            </form>
        </Paper>
    )
}
```

I really can't see the problem here, I'd appriciate if someone could enlighten me! Thanks!!:)

Comment: What is your `./reducers` file? did you use combineReducer?

Comment: Yes, this is how it looks like:


`import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import posts from './posts';

export default combineReducers({ posts });`

Comment: Can you share the code `api.createPost(post)`

Comment: It all seems right to me. Does your app use hot-reload? Did you try killing the npm start and start it again?

Comment: I think your problem might be a duplicate of this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066862/5605822

Comment: @TasosBu Yes, tried it right now but it is the same

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath `export const createPost = (newPost) => axios.post(url, newPost);` this how it looks like

Comment: Can you try removing the dispatch from your `handleSubmit` and just do: `createPost(postData)`?

Comment: everything looks fine, not sure if `try catch` block in the post.js can be an issue as not all code path are returning expected format. Can you remove and try. May be a silly suggestion.

Comment: @TasosBu I have read that question but my code looks like in the answer that was accepted so I don't know what the problem is

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath tried deleting the try catch block but the same error occurs

Comment: So what will happen if the try block throws error? console log will happen at catch block and then nothing is being returned.

Comment: @reClicked you can `console.log` after this line `const { data } = await api.createPost(post);` to check if you are getting expected data back

Comment: Thanks but I found the bug I made. I imported the wrong createPost function, hehe. But thanks for the many tipps!

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your `createStore` method.

1. The first parameter of `createStore` is root reducer which is fine.
   But second parameter should be the initial state and you're passing
   `applyMiddleware` instead of initial state
2. You've to give an array of middlewares to `applyMiddleware` method

```js
// do like this
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware([thunk]));

// not like this
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Comment: Tried both ways but still no luck:/ But thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who answered the question! Turns out I imported the wrong createPost function, silly me! Fortunately everything seems to work now!